# Displaying age in seconds using Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I want to replicate the trick Paul Erdoes used to pull as a child:
Tell someone how many seconds he is old, based on his date of birth and the current time.

This is what the current code looks like:

```
# For displaying age in seconds
from datetime import datetime

year = int(input("year: "))
month = int(input("month: "))
day = int(input("day: "))


# This is resulting in datetime.timedelta object with attr days, seconds, microseconds
#delta = datetime.now() - datetime(year, month, day)
print("You are " + str(datetime.now() - datetime(year, month, day)) + " seconds old.")

#str(delta.seconds)
```

Result is something around 770xx seconds, but that is incorrect, as each day is already 36000 * 24 seconds.

So how do I use the datetime library to perform what I want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [total_seconds](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) to calculate the difference in seconds between two dates

```
from datetime import datetime

year = int(input("year: "))
month = int(input("month: "))
day = int(input("day: "))

#Calculate time in seconds between now and the day of birth
time_in_seconds = (datetime.now() - datetime(year=year, month=month, day=day)).total_seconds()

print("You are {} seconds old.".format(time_in_seconds))
```

The output will be

```
year: 1991
month: 1
day: 31
You are 892979995.504128 seconds old.
```